# What to do after you have trained your machine?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, training-data

Out of curiosity, I have followed some Machine Learning and Deep Learning tutorials but strangely none of them mentioned what to do next with the trained model?

So, what does one do with the trained model? Can it be implemented on a website (for e.g. integrate with Wordpress)?

I'm using colab.

If you have any further resources or tutorials to recommend, please share. Thanks

Comment: There is only one purpose for a trained model: to use what it has learned about some data to predict how similar data will behave. You can use that in a number of different areas - kind of like "the book told me how steel was made, but not what you can use it for", too many uses to list. _How_ exactly to use it is very dependent on your tools. If you are using Google Colaboratory, probably not, as it is mostly an interactive playground, but I am not very familiar with it, which is why you should tag it ([tag:google-colaboratory]) to attract the answerers who have the requisite knowledge.

Comment: @Amadan I am indeed using Google Colaboratory to try my hand at machine learning. While I believe it can be used in a number of different areas, knowing at least one way to deploy it will help to put things in better perspective for beginner. Added the recommended tag. Thanks

Comment: At the bottom of the [welcome page](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb) there is a link to [seedbank](https://research.google.com/seedbank/), which currently shows 117 "end-to-end examples of the interactive machine learning analyses that Colaboratory makes possible". Note "interactive" - you're supposed to learn in the Colab playground, then take the knowledge (and possibly trained models) and use your new Python skills on your own server to actually use machine learning outside the playground.

Answer (score 0):

Once the model is built, further steps include:

- Saving the Machine Learning Model (Pickling the model)
  (In Python, pickling is a standard way to store objects and retrieve them as their original state)
- Creating an API using Flask and deploy it (say, on Azure or AWS).
- Once the deployment is successful, Hit the rest API with input data (feature variables) and get the output (predicted value).

Tutorial to perform the above steps could be found [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/machine-learning-models-as-apis-using-flask/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Parshant mentioned the next step would be deploying (serving) the model

For tensorflow you can have a look at tfx https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving

For pytorch you can have a look at deployment with flask https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/flask_rest_api_tutorial.html